# Изменение кода программы во время ее выполнения

Tags: c, метапрограммирование

В статье [Изменение кода программы во время ее выполнения на примере Common Lisp](http://habrahabr.ru/post/165095/) показывается эта замечательнейшая возможность, но к сожалению только для CL. Скажите пожалуйста, неужели для Си все таки такое проблематично? Ведь есть например [Tiny C Compiler](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler),  который может работать в режиме интерпретатора, а наличие библиотеки libtcc позволяет осуществлять динамическую генерацию кода.

В общем интересует возможность "изменения кода программы во время ее выполнения" для Си.

Comment: Методов "из коробки" нету. Возможные варианты:

* на Юниксе доступен компилятор, так что программа может генерировать исходный код, компилировать его на лету и запускать
* можно реализовать интерпретатор любого языка (хоть того же C), и пропускать через интерпретатор нужные части исходного кода.

Comment: Лучше так вот динамически создавать разделяемую библиотеку и подгружать. Только смысл есть в этом, если код в ней модифицируется редко, а используется часто или выполняет очень массивные расчеты, например. Компилирование - вещь достаточно медленное.

Comment: Чисто теоретически, можете поискать как это делают "взломщики", записывая код в стек (переполнением буфера (это наводка для поиска)) и вызывая его.

Кстати @dreq, утверждение, что это 

     замечательнейшая возможность

весьма спорно. Попробуйте разобраться в **чужой** программе, которая так написана.

Comment: @avp, в линуксе секция стека запрещена к исполнению.

Comment: Да, но техника принципиально не изменится, если вместо стека взять совершенно легально "mmap-нутную" область памяти с разрешением записи и выполнения.

Comment: @avp, именно. Под линуксом даже можно грузить и исполнять виндовые dll (конечно, если они вообще никак не завязаны на winapi). Просто загружая их в обычную память, настраивая релокейшны, точки входа etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для таких целей лучше всего воспользоваться встраиваемым интерпретируемым языком. Очень удобны в этом отношении Lua или Python. Можно, конечно, использовать и tcc, но штука эта довольно примитивная и дальше баловства не идет. Если нужно что-то серьезное - то указанные мощные языки или другие подобные им.

А Си - это компилируемый язык. Поэтому подобное динамическое изменение кода для него более чем проблематично.

Answer (score 1):

[Embeddable Common Lisp](http://ecls.sourceforge.net/) - ECL также может легко встраиваться в приложения написанные на других языках, как скриптовый язык, но с более богатыми возможностями: Common Lisp, компиляция в байт-код или машинный код (если доступен компилятор языка Си).

Answer (score 0):

1. Напишите свой *интерпретатор* Си
2. Дополните базовый язык средствами метапрограммирования (что-нибудь из области pattern matching/replace по AST-дереву сишной программы, может кто ссылку по принципам реализации скинет)
3. Реализуйте динамическую компиляцию (JIT из комплекта LLVM справится ?)

Теорию по метапрограммированию (в одном из вариантов -- школы Турчина) можно попробовать здесь:

- [Интуитовский видеокурс](http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/1067/221/info).
- [учебник](http://window.edu.ru/resource/720/41720)
- [дополнение учебника](http://window.edu.ru/resource/721/41721)

Кто в теме -- накидайте пожалуйста ссылки на лекции/статьи по другим подходам. Особенно интересует метапрограммирование с примененим фреймов Минского, применялись ли и как.

Comment: PS: кто интересно запустил этот бред про интерпретируемые/компилируемые _языки_ ? такое ощущение что преподы никакую классику по CS не видели, и цитируют какую-то драную методичку